# Ruby 2: Forks/Threads, how to calculate efficiency for a specific machine?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Let's say I have a motherboard with 4 CPUs.
Each of the CPUs has 8 cores/16 threads according to Intel.

Now, let's say I have some insane string manipulation task that will take days to finish.
Is there a way to calculate how many forks and threads would yield the best performance?
I'm not sure how many forks and threads I should launch. Plus, I'm not sure if starting threads would even benefit me?

I'm specifically interested in Ruby as I'm not sure how Ruby 2 Threads compare to e.g. C++ Threads.

Comment: This question is very much interpreter-dependent. I don't think the Ruby specification has any requirements regarding thread performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb: 1 process or OS thread for each CPU thread.

For Ruby, at least MRI Ruby, this translates to 1 fork per CPU thread, because MRI Ruby threads can't really execute in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the specifics of the algorithm you're using. There really isn't any general rule.

Consider a task like the following:

1. Drive a truck to point A.
2. Wait for the loader to fill the car with widgets.
3. Drive the truck to point B.
4. With for the unloader to empty the truck.
5. Repeat.

Now, suppose this task moves 1,000 widgets per hour. How many widgets per hour will you move if you add a second truck? Well, you can certainly infer that it's not going to be more than 2,000 widgets per hour.

Why might it be less? Well, what if the driving only takes a tiny bit of the time and the trucks spend lots of time waiting for the loader or unloader to be done with the other truck? What if the road is narrow and the trucks can't easily get around each other?

So in order to know, you have to understand what resources the algorithm is using and how it's using them. Generally, it's difficult enough to predict that the only realistic choice is to measure. You may find that changing the algorithm to one that parallelizes better is possible.

Answer (score 1):

In MRI Ruby, there is little or no benefit running CPU-bound processes in multiple threads, due to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), which essentially means only a single user-level thread will be active at any one time, per Ruby process. JRuby does not have this limitation.

In MRI Ruby you can get parallel work done by using separate processes (via `Process.fork`). There is more overhead in communicating between processes than between threads, but if a problem is made parallel very simply, then this is not a big deal.

This is probably the main difference between (MRI)  Ruby and C++. However, if you have an intensive process to code, then Ruby is not the go-to language - at least not for the central problem you wish to solve. Coding the bulk of the processing in C, C++ or Java may be preferable, using Ruby perhaps for marshalling the inputs and outputs. This is nothing to do with the threading model, but a well-written C library can be 100 times faster than the same thing written in pure Ruby, and if you are talking about a process taking a week on many cores with Ruby, the investment in the different language will pay back very well (it will either take just a couple of hours, or you could do it on a singe core in the same time or less without needing to use threads)

There is no generic formula for determining how many threads or processes are best for a problem. You may hit limitations on management overhead, total memory used etc, before you are able to get maximum use of available CPU. You should *benchmark* performance. Obviously the number of available cores is an important factor, and probably a good guess is to start at 1 thread (or process) per core.